# C# File Encoding Type changed?

Tags: c#, encoding

I am creating a file with `ASCII` encoding, but when I test to get the Encoding type of that file, it is returning `UTF8Encoding`.

Can anyone explain the reason or figure my mistake??

**CODE:**

Creating File:

```
 FileStream _textStream = File.Open("CreateAsciiFile.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
 StreamWriter _streamWriter = new StreamWriter(_textStream, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);

 Byte[] byteContent = BtyeTowrite();  // This returns the array of byte
 foreach(var myByte in byteContent)
    _streamWriter.Write(System.Convert.ToChar(myByte));
```

Reading a file:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\CreateAsciiFile.txt",true);
string LineText= sr.ReadLine();
System.Text.Encoding enc = sr.CurrentEncoding;
```

Here enc gives `UTF8Encoding`... But I am expecting `ASCII` ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read from the reader before querying the encoding. So before calling `sr.CurrentEncoding` try reading something. The StreamReader looks at the first bytes to try to *guess* the encoding and because ASCII has no BOM it might not be recognizable as such and you might get wrong results. For example there is no difference (at the binary level) between an ASCII encoded file a `ISO-8859-1` encoded file.

Comment: Ok.. but that way also returns the same encoding type

Answer (score 1):

The answer is probably [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8):"

> Every valid ASCII character is also a valid UTF‑8 encoded Unicode character with the same binary value.

In other words, your ASCII file is both valid UTF-8 and ASCII. It is detected as UTF-8.

Comment: If it is correct then ASCII should be worthless.... Might it is correct?? But if I am saving it as ASCII why it is returning UTF8....?

Comment: ASCII fits inside UTF8 but the reverse is not true. UTF8 isn't the same as ASCII. You get UTF8 because ASCII is also UTF8 compatible.